# Can't open Windows data disk in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, disk

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside with Windows 10 64-bit and I can't open my Windows data disk when I am in Ubuntu.

I understand that I must mount all disk for this Ubuntu?

[image: [All my disks image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBkFR.jpg)]

Answer (score 1):

You can view your internal drives for windows with a few configurations.

1. Update first - `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install `ntfs-3g` - `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`
3. Make a Directory for windows mount-point - `sudo mkdir /media/Windows`
4. Check the partition where windows was installed - `sudo fdisk -l`
   (look for the system it should say /dev/sda2 HFPS/NTFS)
5. Use `ntfs-3g` - `sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /media/Windows`
   (Apply respectively to your Windows partition Assuming /dev/sda5 up to /dev/sda8)

Depends on which drive of your windows you need and make sure to create separate mount-points respectively

This should allow you to mount your windows partition and access to it. if you are done its safer to unmount it

6. Unmount - `sudo umount /media/***`

Hope this helps

Comment: `ntfs-3g` should already be installed in a default Ubuntu 16.04 (at least it's in [the manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest)) so installing it should't be necessary, but can check with `apt show ntfs-3g` or `apt-cache...`. Shouldn't `mount` alone work?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, on my case i've use ntfs-3g and mount alone didn't work for me.

Comment: Interesting. just checked it's man page and it seems to imply `ntfs-3g` and `mount -t ntfs-3g` are equivalent, but mount could auto-try the wrong type without the `-t ntfs-3g` part. Also mentions that windows may leave it's drives "in an inconsistent state" if hibernating or doing "fast restarts"...

Comment: if you mount those drives from nautilus you don't need to create the mountpoint subdirectory in media, they will be created and deleted automatically. :)

Comment: Yes, i know its really something but that's how it works for me, another one will be the NTFS configuration tool in Ubuntu software the OP can use it the same as with these approach this was the only one i've encountered so yeah.

Comment: Hello friends you are very nice to answer so quickly! I have reched to point Check the partition where windows was installed - sudo fdisk -l
(look for the system it should say /dev/sda2 HFPS/NTFS) and receive anatoli@anatoli-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~$ sudo fdisk -1
fdisk: invalid option -- '1'

Usage:
 fdisk [options] <disk>      change partition table
 fdisk [options] -l [<disk>] list partition table(s)

Display or manipulate a disk partition table.


For more details see fdisk(8).
anatoli@anatoli-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~$ " fdisk
invalid opt

Comment: For more details see fdisk(8).
anatoli@anatoli-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~$ sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /media/Windows
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
anatoli@anatoli-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~$

Comment: may be it will be more simpli for insert keyon//// flash and reinstal from begining?

Comment: in that case use this command to terminate the hibernation of windows drive properly: sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5 then run again sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /media/Windows